# UseEffect works locally but not In production Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, deployment, vercel

**I am using NextJs**
I'm fetching posts when the component loads, and the code works well locally. However, on Vercel, the feed only fetches the posts once. If I create a new post and then redirect to the feed page, it should fetch the latest posts again. But on Vercel, it's not fetching the latest posts and keeps showing the old ones.

My Feed component code

```
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import PromptCard from "./PromptCard";

const PromptCardList = ({ data, handleTagClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="mt-16 prompt_layout">
      {
        data.map((post) => (
          <PromptCard
            key={post.id}
            post={post}
            handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
          />
        ))
      }

    </div>
  )
}

const Feed = () => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  // search states
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')
  const [searchedResults, setSearchedResults] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/api/prompt');
      const data = await response.json();
      setPosts(data);
    }

    fetchPosts();
  
  }, [])

  // main searchin part, using regex
  const filterPrompts = (searchtext) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchtext, "i"); // 'i' flag for case-insensitive search
    return posts.filter(
      (item) =>
        regex.test(item.creator.username) ||
        regex.test(item.tag) ||
        regex.test(item.prompt)
    );
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value)

    const searchResult = filterPrompts(e.target.value);
    setSearchedResults(searchResult);

  }
  const handleTagClick = (tagName) => {
    setSearchText(tagName)
    const searchResult = filterPrompts(tagName);
    setSearchedResults(searchResult);
  }

  return (
    <section className="feed">
      <form className="relative w-full flex-center">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for a tag or username"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
          required
          className="search_input peer"
        />
      </form>

      {searchText ? (
        <PromptCardList
          data={searchedResults}
          handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
        />
      ) : (
        <PromptCardList data={posts} handleTagClick={handleTagClick} />
      )}

    </section>
  )
}

export default Feed
```

Github: [Github repo](https://github.com/sudhanshugautam2911/share_propmts)

Deployed Link: [live website](https://share-propmts-git-master-simple-mart-ecommerces-projects.vercel.app/)
or
[Link 2](https://share-propmts-simple-mart-ecommerces-projects.vercel.app/)

The latest posts are not being fetched on Vercel as expected. I'm not sure where the problem lies. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please do checkout this [closed](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48754) github issue.